# How to model OO scenario

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I recurrently run into an scenario similar to this:

A container business class that models a hierarchy.

A business class that participates in this hierarchy and is aggregated by the aforementioned class.

Let me give you an example.

A `Map` has Countries. Now the `Map` should know where each `Country` is, since its main responsability besides containing all countries is to know the locations and proximity of each. From this point of view, a functionality such as `isNeighbour(Country A, Country B)` seems like a correct addition to `Map`. However, each Country should also offer a method to know if a country is nearby. Say `spain.isNeighbour(italy)`. This is indeed useful. Now, if I don't want to duplicate functionality and responsability, what approach should I take?

The current example I am working on is something for my university, each course requires other courses and also blocks the next level ones. The major is the one that contains all courses and dictates which course precedes which. Say I want to add a dependency of a course over another, e.g to take Calculus 2 you need Calculus 1... Should I go `calculus.addRequired(calculus2)` and then pass it to the major object, or maybe `computerScience.addRequired(calculus1, calculus2)`...

I don't want to have both alternatives because to me it seems it can lead to error, but at the same time I want each course to be able to answer what are its requirements. I don't really know how to distribute responsabilities correctly.

Comment: Is this tied to data persistence/databases or is it all in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is, that there is no problem calling each other.

You can have

```
boolean Map.isNeighbour(Country A, Country B) { return A.isNeighbour(B); }
```

or

```
boolean Country.isNeighbour(Country other) { return map.isNeighbour(this, other); }
```

Second seems to need reference to global map. First makes Map look like simple facade.

Second thing is that you say it is persisted. There also might be good idea to create a service, that will query DB with related parameters. This can be either Map or some repository service. This will also allow you to query with only identities of entities (eg. countryId) instead of full objects.

I believe neither of the solutions is better or worse. Only point of difference is where other developers expect the methods to be located. But when I think about it, this would mean Map will have all responsibilities of Country, thus breaking SRP, especially if it is not call-through to the country method.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the `isNeighbour()` method into `Country`.
`Country` would contain a map of neighbours. And then the container can call this method on the country instance in question.

This way the logic is maintained by the countries, and the container simply delegates to answer the question to them.

In case of courses it is possible that Course-1 is required for Course-2 in Major-1, but not in Major-2. In this case I would introduce another class, e.g. CourseInMajor that would contain the required courses for a given course in a given Major.